# filetype dependent alias in bash

Tags: bash, vim, alias

I am trying make a filetype dependent gvim alias in bashrc as:

```
if [[ $file == *.tex ]]; then
  alias vi="/home/rudra/bin/vims.py"
else
  alias vi="gvim"
fi
```

And I am expecting to run `~/bin/vims.py foo.tex` for `vi foo.tex` file, and `gvim bar.txt` when I type `vi bar.txt`. But, its not working, and only running `gvim foo.{tex/txt}` for all extensions.

It is also showing:

```
which vi
alias vi='gvim'
    /usr/bin/gvim
```

So I guess, if condition for *.tex is not working at all.
Any idea why?

I am using:

```
bash --version 
GNU bash, version 4.3.43(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

\vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Jan 26 2017 07:53:42)
```

also:

```
vi --version
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `--version'
```

Comment: In `zsh` there is `suffix` alias `alias -s tex=$editor`, seen [here](https://superuser.com/a/864109/411849). Switch to zsh however is for another day and not always recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a shell function, `edit`, that will open a file with an editor.  It defaults to `gvim`, but if the file has a `.tex` suffix it chooses another editor:

```
function edit
{
    typeset argc="$#"
    typeset file="${!argc}"

    typeset cmd="gvim"

    case "$file" in
        *.tex)  cmd="/home/rudra/bin/vims.py" ;;
    esac

    command "$cmd" "$@"
}
```

This makes it easy to add other editors for specific filename suffixes.

This function may be put in your `~/.bashrc` file.

The `bash` manual contains the statement

> For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions.

Comment: I doubt `For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions.` as aliases are `quick and dirty` which is super these days. With `zsh` you have even more alias options and flags like `-s` and `-g`.

Comment: @Timo This question is about the `bash` shell and I was quoting the shell's manual. If you want to question the quote, please do so on the `help-bash` mailing list.